# Having an issue with subtitle text not centering, and green bar showing on the right side

Tags: html, css

Can't figure out why the subtitle text won't center and why the green background moves out from underneath the pictures when moving through responsive constraints. I'm sure there is an easy fix, but I have some overlapping CSS that I think may be cancelling others out.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I suggest all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  Please note that posting an image of text is not considered acceptable on the site-- a [mcve] of code as text should be included in the body of the question.  Without meeting that minimum requirement, the community will be extremely limited in how much guidance they can provide, and the question is at high risk of being closed.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: It seems to me the text is actually centred compared to the image, but the page exceeds on the right side.
Looks like there is some element that makes the page larger than it's supposed to be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Inline blocks" for the pictures. The pictures porperites could be not responsive so check it out. For some css properties use "!important" to make them stay the way you want them to.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Thank you!